# How do I fix this in CiviCRM System Status - sites/default/civicrm/extensions is not writable Please change your file permissions?

Tags: installation, permissions, 4.7

I'm getting a warning message in CiviCRM System Status while setting up 4.7 - "sites/default/civicrm/extensions is not writable. Please change your file permissions." What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at the first answer to this question - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/168/are-there-recommended-directory-ownership-and-permission-settings-for-civicrm-fi#comment19968_168

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be able to download and install extensions automatically, you need to either change the owner of your folder sites/default/civicrm/extensions to www-data and/or change its access rights so www-data can write into it

Comment: Thanks Xavier - what are the steps to do that?

Comment: I would do it from the command line (chown or cmod), but probably an option/permission on your ftp client too