# Moving CiviCRM from Windows to Linux

Tags: installation, civicrm-home, install

I created a CiviCRM database locally on my windows machine on Wordpress. I am using a linux webserver to which I would like to move the data. I think there should be no issues in moving the data using phpmyadmin. Will there be any issues due to difference in OS ?

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC32/Moving+the+database+using+phpMyAdmin

What other issues can be expected due to this movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Drupal you need to update the temporary files folder under Administer - Configuration - File System, and possibly in the files table you might have paths using a backslash that need to be converted.

Also even for non-drupal for the windows to linux direction pay attention to capitalization for any file paths. Linux is case-sensitive but windows is not.

And your civicrm.settings.php file may need updating for backslashes and capitalization.

File permissions and file/folder ownership also tend to be more varied on linux. You may have to grant permission to the web server (see e.g. [Are there recommended directory ownership and permission settings for CiviCRM files?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/168/are-there-recommended-directory-ownership-and-permission-settings-for-civicrm-fi))