# Problems with file permission and ownership at civicrm/templates_c

Tags: permissions, cron, templates, cache, webserver

I always set my file permissions under the templates_c folder like in the [Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/168/are-there-recommended-directory-ownership-and-permission-settings-for-civicrm-fi) to username:www-data and the permissions to 770. It runs fine on other systems, but I have a system which is only runs fine until there appear more cached stuff in the folder. The new files have strange combinations of ownership like username:username or www-data:www-data. Also they have the wrong permissions set. The username:username get 664 the www-data:www-data 644.

Now i tried to set the ownership of my folder to username:www-data with 770. Then webinterface of civicrm doesnt work. If i set the folder to www-data:www-data the system works, but the civicrm related cronjobs from username doesnt work.

Is there a superior file permission i dont see here, but is correct on my other systems? I always do the same stuff like in the link suggested when i set my permissions. I cant get to the point why the system has this strange behavior, all because of a template cache.

Comment: You might have a cron script that runs as `username`. If possible set the cron script to run as `www-data`.

Comment: But isnt the `www-data` the apache-"user"? The `username` is the "owner" and "manager" of the crm. Why cant i logically divide the roles like that?

Comment: The `www-data` apache "user" needs write access to everything in templates_c. If `username` creates a file/folder in there and `www-data` doesn't also have write access to it, you get fails.

Comment: Yes, but thats the reason why i set the whole folder to `username:www-data` and the permissions to 770 so that when there is a new folder or file, it doesnt have to be a problem, or do i understand you wrong?

Comment: For that to work though you would need to put the two users in the same group, or start messing with umask and setuid bits. Currently and NEW subfolders/files created by one user will not be writable by the other.